# Is it possible to have a batch file input text into an application?

Tags: batch-file, dosbox

i.e. having a batch file automatically enter text into dos box to open games?
I'm trying to get Elder Scrolls Daggerfall to run automatically. It has an inconvenient amount of lines to input before actually being able to play. The lines I'd like it to input into DOSBox are:

- mount c c:\dosgames -freesize 1000
- mount d c:\dosgames\dfcd -t cdrom -label Daggerfall
- c:
- cd\dagger
- dagger

I've tried taking an easier route and setting up a desktop shortcut to launch the game like on the [wiki](http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/DOSBoxShortcuts) but haven't had any luck with that.

Answer (score 1):

From DosBox's Help

> AUTOMATION: Do I always have to type these commands?
>       In the DOSBox configuration file is an [autoexec] section. The commands
>       present there are run when DOSBox starts, so you can use this section
>       for the mounting. Look at Section 13: The configuration (options) file

Comment: That will work, but isn't always convenient. For instance, the `autoexec` section will be run each time DosBox is run, not only when he wants to play that particular game.